# Lombok @Singular - how to make it threadsafe?

Tags: java, lombok, builder

This is a question about [Lombok's `@Builder` and `@Singular` annotations](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) and thread safety

As a simplified example, consider this class:

```
@Builder
public class Avengers {
    @Singular
    private List<String> members;
}
```

This generates a builder, where I can do this:

```
final Avengers team = Avengers.builder()
    .member("Iron Man")
    .member("Thor")
    .member("Captain America")
    .build();
System.out.println(team.getMembers());  // ["Iron Man", "Thor", "Captain America"]
```

**Now for the problem** - what I want to do is something like this (again, this is oversimplified to make the point):

```
final AvengersBuilder teamBuilder = Avengers.builder();
executorService.submit(() -> teamBuilder.member("Iron Man"));
executorService.submit(() -> teamBuilder.member("Thor"));
executorService.submit(() -> teamBuilder.member("Captain America"));
// shutdown and awaitTermination would go here

final Avengers team = teamBuilder.build();
```

**Why is this a problem?**

The generated builder is not threadsafe (Lombok backs it by an `ArrayList`), so the result of `team.getMembers()` may be incomplete or in an inconsistent state due to this.

**Question: Is there a way to have Lombok generate a threadsafe builder that lets me use this "Singular" pattern?**

My workaround thus far has been to avoid Singular and create my own threadsafe builder methods, but I'm hoping to eliminate this boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Anyway, trying to share a builder across multiple threads is highly unusual. You'd do much better to store all the results, then iterate them and add them all to the builder on the same thread.

```
List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();  
futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> "Iron Man"));
futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> "Thor"));
futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> "Captain America"));
// shutdown and awaitTermination would go here

final AvengersBuilder teamBuilder = Avengers.builder();
for (Future<String> future : futures) {
    try {
        teamBuilder.member(future.get());
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // do something
    }
}
final Avengers team = teamBuilder.build();
```

This still parallelizes the generation of the items, which is presumably the slow part.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of - was hoping I was missing some "trick" within Lombok to make this look how I wanted :)